# Shortest path in a circular, undirected, unweighted graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have a circular network, beginning with each node connected to its nearest neighbor.  I add a certain amount of long range connections, with longer connections becoming exceedingly less likely.

[It can be represented like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZQBL.png)

[and it is stored in a 2D array like this](http://pastebin.com/uk1cgyDp)

I would like to create a routine that randomly selects two nodes and finds the shortest path between them.  What would be the most effective algorithm for achieving this?

Comment: You may want to ask that on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). There's several shortest path algorithms, the most popular is Dijkstra's one.

Comment: Take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm. It's a classic approach to solving this question, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

There's well known algorithm for this called as Dijkstra's algorithm. I have heard that name before I got to know what graphs are...

EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION:- As far as difference b/w Prism and Dijkstra's is concerned:-

Prim's algorithm constructs a minimum spanning tree for the graph, which is a tree that connects all nodes in the graph and has the least total cost among all trees that connect all the nodes. However, the length of a path between any two nodes in the MST might not be the shortest path between those two nodes in the original graph.

Dijkstra's algorithm constructs a shortest path tree starting from some source node. A shortest path tree is a tree that connects all nodes in the graph and has the property that the length of any path from some start node to any other node in the graph is minimized.

So, if shortest path is between two nodes is concerned then go for Dijkstra's. I don't know much about other options but Kruskal is drwan along the same line as Prim.

Comment: Yes, I've heard the name as well, along with Prim, Kruskal, Floyd and many others.

Comment: @Gerald So, you just have to try them now ;)

Comment: Thanks!  I will attempt an implementation of Dijkstra's.